# How do I pass arguments to google chrome when running selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to be able to pass arguments to google chrome when running selenium. How can I do that? When I run selenium I use the Java command Java -jar selenium.jar

How can I pass arguments such as no-sandbox, ignore-gpu-blacklist, enable-webgl to google chrome executable. Thanks

I'm using nightwatch

Comment: You can have a look at ChromeOptions class in Java and\or DesiredCapabilities. Then use that object to create the driver. http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ page usually has a dump of options available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send them in your method for launching the driver. e.g.

```
public static WebDriver chromeBrowser() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver-location\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return browser;
    }
```

Comment: Person is using nightwatch.js, you have mentioned Java code.

Comment: @Grasshopper But you get what he meant

Answer (score 2):

In [`nightwatch`](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Chrome-Setup) you should include `chromeOptions` with `no-sandbox` args into `desiredCapabilities` as below :-

```
"desiredCapabilities" : {
  "browserName" : "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled" : true,
  "acceptSslCerts" : true,
  "chromeOptions" : {
    "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is I am using javascript with WebDriver?