# Take screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot on test failure.

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stackTrace = "<pre>" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message + "</pre>";
        var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
        if (status == NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, status + errorMessage);
            var ScreenShotPath = GetScreenShot.Capture(_webdriverChrome);
            test.Log(LogStatus.Fail, "Screen Shot Below: "+test.AddScreenCapture(ScreenShotPath));
        }
        else if (status == NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.TestStatus.Passed)
        {
            test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, status + errorMessage);
        }
        extent.EndTest(test);
        _webdriverChrome.Quit();}
```

and the capture function is

```
 public static string Capture(IWebDriver Webdrievr)
    {
        string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;

        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Webdrievr).GetScreenshot();
        string screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
        byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;
        ss.SaveAsFile(projectPath + "ErrorReportScreenshot\\ErrorScreenshot.jpeg", ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg); //use any of the built in image formating
        string _fullPathToReturn = projectPath + "ErrorReportScreenshot";
        return _fullPathToReturn;
    }
```

I'm getting an error

> Result Message:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56184/session/1aaf976356898c52e5cd57d17d44df15/element timed out after 60 seconds.
>     ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
>   TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56184/session/1aaf976356898c52e5cd57d17d44df15/screenshot timed out after 60 seconds.
>     ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out

The thing is that it fails taking the screenshots as long as I'm calling the `capture()` method from `TearDown()`.
If I'm just calling the `capture()` by running it within a new test, it works like a charm. 
In debugging mode, I can see it fails on this row: `Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Webdrievr).GetScreenshot();`
what am I missing?

EDIT:
I have watched the `((ITakesScreenshot)Webdrievr)` and getting an error:

> error CS0103: The name 'Webdrievr' does not exist in the current context

Call Stack:

```
>   Assign_Represnt.dll!Assign_Represnt.GetScreenShot.Capture(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver Webdrievr) Line 22 C#
```

Comment: Did you check the cast to `ITakesScreenShot` works ?

Comment: what do you mean? how should I do that? as I said , if I'm running it just as a standalone test and not under Teardown, it works.

Comment: Do you call `_webdriverChrome.Quit();` or `_webdriverChrome.Close();` in any other place before `TearDown`?

Comment: In debugging, add (ITakesScreenshot)Webdrievr to your watch and see what the result is. But the cast must be ok, I missed you were getting a timeout error.

Comment: @Guy I am quitting the driver during my test, but I'm not even getting to this point. the test failes much before. there's a text I'm looking for(as an element) and once the driver can't find it, the test fails and goes to the Teardown

Comment: You are getting `Webdrievr` does not exist **inside** your capture method ? Does not make sense, it's a local variable to Capture. Can you show us the exact call to Capture that is being called, as it shows in Visual studio's Call Stack?

Comment: updated my post again with the call stack(hope that what you mean). the other problem is that the driver in Teardown isn't quit as it stops in that point where the screenshot fails

Comment: Bit late, but to me the issue looks like: (ITakesScreenshot)Webdrievr, here: Webdrievr needs to be a reference to the driver variable that you have created. Perhaps it was a typo?

Comment: I got a similar issue: "Message=A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61765/session//screenshot. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it Source=WebDriver". The reason was I mistakenly used driver.Quit() before TearDown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem . for some reason the following caused all of this

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
_webdriverChrome = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I just used the chromedriver without options and it works now.

```
_webdriverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39041495/3110529 this question shows the argument for no sandbox is actually `"--no-sandbox"`, could have been that but not entirely convinced.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue while trying to take screenshot upon test failure. I get timed out error when I try to take the screenshot on failure condition. It works fine in try block but timed out in catch block. I am not using Chrome options as the solution provided above. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the method to take screenshot:

```
public class Logging
    {
      public static void ErrorScreenshot()
        {
        //Take the screenshot
        Screenshot ssh = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver.BrowserInstance).GetScreenshot();
        //Save the screenshot
        ssh.SaveAsFile("C:/Users/", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        } 
     }
```

This is my test method

```
public static bool FindElement
    {
      get
      {
          try
          {
             var element = Driver.BrowserInstance.FindElement(By.XPath("  "));
             if (element != null)
             {
               return true;
             }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             Logging.ErrorScreenshot();
             Logging.Error("Not able to find element" + ex.ToString());
          }
          return false;
     }

  }
```

when it is not able to find the element it goes to catch block and there Logging.ErrorScreenshot method throws a timed out exception.

```
Error details below:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55418/session/f3dbde1645dd91e453c5823d72199ea9/screenshot timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()
   at Logging.ErrorScreenshot() in C:\Users\Logging.cs:line 66
   at DashboardPage.get_Verifylogin() in C:\Users\DasboardPage.cs:line 65
   at Tests() in C:\Users\SmokeTests\Tests.cs:line 33

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The operation has timed out
```