# selenium chrome driver without cache

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium, caching

Maybe someone know how to surfing in Chrome without using browser cache?
I run in loop get the pages in the incognito-mode and do not close the browser. But it seems it used cache, because the browser did not close.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-java")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
i = 1
while i < 10:
    driver.get('https://selenium.com') 
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Try using Chrome sandbox mode as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041495/842245

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the following every time you navigate to a different page.

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

or you could just simply browse to the cache page within chrome itself and click the "clear browsing data" button via selenium.

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

Comment: Hi! Is it only delete cookies or cache also?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, you may want to check that out yourself.  You could just possibly browse to the chrome clear cache page and use selenium to click the "clear browsing data".  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *Chrome* with **--disable-application-cache** argument, which is equivalent to "Private mode"

Answer (score 0):

I know that post is old but for those who are in 2020 is looking for solution( all browsers and not only chrome) that can be achieved with BrowserMob(BrowserUP) proxy itself - you can set a rules on requests and responses that will delete headers related to caching mechanisms in browsers( there are lot of them). Below are scripts I use( them might be incomplete so if you found what is missing please let know):

Requests:

```
curl --location --request POST 'your_proxy_api_host:your_proxy_api_port/proxy/your_proxy_port/filter/request' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'request.headers().remove('\''If-Modified-Since'\'');request.headers().remove('\''If-None-Match'\'');'
```

Response:

```
curl --location --request POST '0.0.0.0:8080/proxy/8081/filter/response' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'response.headers().remove('\''Age'\'');response.headers().remove('\''ETag'\'');response.headers().remove('\''Cache-Control'\'');response.headers().remove('\''Expires'\'');response.headers().remove('\''Last-Modified'\'');response.headers().remove('\''Vary'\'');response.headers().add('\''Expires'\'', 0);response.headers().add('\''Cache-Control'\'', '\''private'\'');response.headers().add('\''Cache-Control'\'', '\''no-cache'\'');response.headers().add('\''Cache-Control'\'', '\''no-store'\'');response.headers().add('\''Cache-Control'\'', '\''must-revalidate'\'');response.headers().add('\''Vary'\'', '\''*'\'');'
```

I work with http 1.1 so I didn't add anything for http 1.0 or http 2.0. Checked on Chrome Edge Safari FF.
Also, I use little proxy api( new api of browsermob) - for [reference](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#rest-api-interceptors-with-littleproxy)